# Javascript - If statement blocking code

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, if-statement

This is the code I have: https://hastebin.com/loqicunulu.js (too large to post here)

I want it so if I do `!warn USER REASON` it adds them to a json file, which it does,

then if I do it again `!warn USER REASON` it will kick them as they've already been warned (line 13) - don't want them to be added the the json file here.

But at the moment it just keeps on adding them to the json file every time I do it, and doesn't kick them.

I think it is completely skipping my if statment.

Comment: The result of require('xxx.json') will be cached!

Comment: Include your code. If tomorrow hastebin no longer exists, this question will have lost any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're only including modlogs.json one time, at the beginning of execution. After you add the user to the warn list, you're not updating the warn list in memory with the new contents. Instead of including the modlog like that, try just moving your if statement into the fs.readFile callback. That way you have the latest contents of the file to check against.

**disclaimer**: this code is not tested, but it should give you the direction you need to go in, and might just work out of the box.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" "); // joins every argument after the first
  let user = message.mentions.users.first(); // grabs the first user mentioned
  let modLog = client.channels.find("name", "mod-log"); // find the channel to post to
  if (!modLog) return message.reply("No channel named `mod-log` found.").catch(console.error); // sanity check
  if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply("You must mention someone to warn.").catch(console.error); // sanity check
  if (args.length < 2) return message.reply("You must supply a reason.").catch(console.error); // sanity check

  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../moderation") + "/modlogs.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) { // read the JSON file
    if (err) throw err; // throw error if applicable

    var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data); // parse the data
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.warns.length; i++) { // loop through all keys in warns file
      if (arrayOfObjects.warns[i].user_id === user.id) {
        message.reply("User already warned. Kicking user.");
        message.guild.member(user).kick(); // kicks member
        return;
      }
    }
    
    arrayOfObjects.warns.push({ // push the data into the array
      user: `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`,
      user_id: `${user.id}`,
      mod: `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`,
      mod_id: `${message.author.id}`,
      reason: reason
    });

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../moderation") + "/modlogs.json", JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects, null, 2), "utf-8", function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() // send embed of warning
      .setColor(0x00AE86)
      .addField("Action:", "Warning")
      .addField("User:", `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}\nUserID: ${user.id}`)
      .addField("Mod:", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}\nUserID: ${message.author.id}`)
      return client.channels.get(modLog.id).sendEmbed(embed); // send embed to mod-log channel
    });
  });
};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: false,
  aliases: [],
  permLevel: 1
};

exports.help = {
  name: "warn",
  description: "Warns a mentioned user.",
  usage: "warn <mention> <reason>"
};
```